# Do we define the cycle graph for $n<3$?

Tags: graph-theory

I am taking a course in graph theory. In this course, all graphs shall be undirected, and have either $0$ or $1$ edges between vertices. We have defined in lectures that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the cycle graph $C_n$ has vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$ where

$V=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, $E=\{x_1x_2, x_2x_3, \dots x_{x-1}x_n, x_nx_1\}.$

The graphs with one vertex, and two vertices connected by an edge, are not cycles, yet they fit the pattern of how the graphs $C_n$ are defined. Would we ever refer to $C_1$ and $C_2$, or if there was some result where I wanted to show “for every cycle graph, X”, just assume $n \geq 3$?

Comment: It is a matter of convention and also of whether your graphs are directed, undirected, with or without multiple edges, with or without loops etc., which your notation is very vague about.

Comment: Note that in your definition of *cycle*, your enumeration of the edge set’s extension includes both $x_1 x_2$ and $x_n x_1$. Since notational convention has it that single braces { and } are used to denote straightforward sets (unless otherwise indicated), in which multiplicities of membership don’t happen, one would **tend to** conclude that by your definition there can be no $n$-cycles for $n <3$. And for simple, undirected graphs, that is the case.  But this is (at least part of) the vagueness to which @MichalAdamaszek has objected.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you for pointing this out. I shall clarify the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with simple graphs, we only define $C_n$ for $n\ge 3$.

Cycle graphs $C_1$ and $C_2$ *are* occasionally defined in the case of multigraphs, in which case $C_1$ is a vertex with a loop, and $C_2$ is a pair of vertices with two parallel edges between them. *These* definitions have properties matching the other cycles $C_n$, such as:

- The graph $C_n$ should have $n$ vertices and $n$ edges.
- If any edge is deleted, the result should be isomorphic to $P_n$ (following the convention that $P_n$ is the $n$-*vertex* path).
- No tree graph has a subgraph isomorphic to $C_n$ for any $n$.

There are no simple graphs with these properties that can be defined for $n=1$ and $n=2$, so we don't define $C_1$ and $C_2$ in the world of simple graphs. (It is still fine to define complete graphs $K_1$ and $K_2$, and path graphs $P_1$ and $P_2$, which are the same thing in both cases.)